# How to set an icon on the active page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to set an icon for a specific page. I use this code:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active:true,windowType:"normal", currentWindow: true},function(d){
    console.log( d[0].id)
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
        path: {
          "16": "/assets/fav2.png",
          'tabId': d[0].id
        }
      });
})
```

In the console:

```
327
GET chrome-extension://oalddlcbkeallmfceaindbiokfibecgd/327 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Could not load action icon '327'.
```

If I write this code:

```
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
  path: {
    "16": "/assets/fav2.png"        
  }
});
```

Everything is working.

How can I set an icon on a specific page?

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the `tabId` in the wrong place. This is what you want:

```
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
    path: {"16": "/assets/fav2.png"},
    tabId: d[0].id
});
```